# Numpy multiply array with specific column

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Im not sure, how I would go about doing this (preferably in an efficient manner) -

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

I want to to multiply [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] with [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] (column 3 in b) in an efficient way.
Without computing a new array. Efficiency is required to train some of my models faster. This becomes especially useful when dimensions are pretty high.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Numpy` has very efficient matrix/vector operations.
If you want the dot product between `a` and the third column of `b` you can do

```
a.dot(b[:,2])
# returns 15
```

and if you want the element-wise multiplication, you can do

```
np.multiply(a, b[:,2])
# returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```